# react-select async creatable does not recommend

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to use [AsyncCreatableSelect](https://react-select.com/creatable) with example data :

```
[
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
]
```

My code looks like this :

```
const fetchData = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve=>{
        resolve([
            { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
            { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
            { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
        ])
    })
}

const component = () => {
    return(
            <AsyncCreatableSelect
                cacheOptions
                defaultOptions
                loadOptions={fetchGameList}
            />
    );
}
```

And the problem is that, the data is correctly loaded but when I type, I don't get any recommendation compared to the examples on the website :

[image: Example]

Whatever I type in the input, the result is always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the documentation you linked, it includes the "filterColors" function. You need to implement a similar or equivalent function, and wrap the return value of the "loadOptions" function in it, the same way they do.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import AsyncCreatableSelect from 'react-select/async-creatable';
import { colourOptions } from '../data';

const filterColors = (inputValue: string) => {
  return colourOptions.filter(i =>
    i.label.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase())
  );
};

const promiseOptions = inputValue =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(filterColors(inputValue));
    }, 1000);
  });

export default class WithPromises extends Component<*, State> {
  render() {
    return (
      <AsyncCreatableSelect
        cacheOptions
        defaultOptions
        loadOptions={promiseOptions}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Refer to "promiseOptions" above, which is the function used for "loadOptions".The inputValue returned is wrapped in the "filterColors" function, which does the sorting.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if your `fetchGameList` already returned the sorted list. Your backend would do the sorting.

Answer (score -1):

It's better to use something like useMemo or useCallback and in that list or return add array which you need to present.

You can type

```
const data = useMemo(() => { ...code... }, [deps])
```

In ...code... you can type your code but in deps you can watch some variable and once when deps is changed your useMemo will be triggered again...

Comment: How is that relevant to filtering/searching results?